# I am running into the error req.user.role is Undefined in the below code

Tags: node.js

```
exports.authorize = (roles)=> {
    return(req,res,next)=>{
        
        if(!roles.includes(req.user.role)){
            console.log(req.user.role)
            return res.status(401).json({msg:`The role ${req.user.role} not authorized"})
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you log `console.log(req.user)` ? And where do you assign `req.user`?

Comment: are you assigning req.user somehwere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.authorizedRoles = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      console.log(req.user.role)
      return res.status(401).json({
        msg: `The role ${req.user.role} not authorized`
      })
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).